How do I update a date column to be 31 days based on the value on start_date column?



SEQ
Start_date
End_date




1
2024/09/20 01:00:00



2
2024/09/23 01:00:00




Based on the above I want to update end_date to be 31 days counting from start_date. I want to do this to multiple rows on a table with different start_date all at once.
I did try DATEADD() method but Oracle invalidates it.
update table1
set end_date = dateadd(day,31,start_date )
where seq in (select seq from table2);
the error message is :
ORA-00904: "DATEADD": invalid identifier

You need to use Oracle syntax, not SQL Server or other database-specific syntax. SQL has many flavours.
